# Nested CollectionView reading MultiDimensionalArrray to populate cells

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view inside another collection view.  I can have the inner view populate its cells with a static array of data ( so each of the outer collection views cells contain the same number of inner cells)

Outer-A - 7-Inner cells visible
Outer-B - 7-Inner cells visible

[image]

Now i am trying to have each of the outer cells populated with the data from a multi dimensional array.

A print of the array shows the following in the console.

```
[[ParseStarterProject_Swift.CollectionStruct(name: "pk000-01", description: “This is some text.”, title: "Session 1", image: <PFFile: 0x60000045a790>, id: "WCzjfdJgox"), ParseStarterProject_Swift.CollectionStruct(name: "pk000-02", description: “This is some more text.”, title: "session 2", image: <PFFile: 0x608000447d40>, id: "0yth6YSxbe")]
[ParseStarterProject_Swift.CollectionStruct(name: "pk010-01", description: "Im just testing stuff", title: "Session 1", image: <PFFile: 0x600000454850>, id: "SQYvJTvJwE"), ParseStarterProject_Swift.CollectionStruct(name: "pk010-02", description: "This is some more text about nothing", title: "Session 2", image: <PFFile: 0x60000045b540>, id: "0z6rw6gPVp")]
[ParseStarterProject_Swift.CollectionStruct(name: "pk020-01", description: "Session 1", title: "Session 1", image: <PFFile: 0x608000448910>, id: "vGIjK3jEjc")]]
```

So in the cellForItemAt function i would like to only show items from the first item of the array within the first cell.  (items from line 1 of the array in the orange cell).

This is my cellForItemAt function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    if collectionView == self.outerCollectionView {
        let outerCell: OuterCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierOuter, for: indexPath) as! OuterCollectionCell

        outerCell.labelCell.text = self.packArray[indexPath.item].title
        outerCell.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        let temp = myColorArray[indexPath.item].color
        if let hexValue = UInt(String(temp.characters.suffix(6)), radix: 16) {
            outerCell.contentView.backgroundColor = GeneralFunctions.UIColorFromHEX(hexValue: hexValue)

        }

        return outerCell

    } else {

        let innerCell: InnerCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierInner, for: indexPath) as! InnerCollectionCell

            //innerCell.imageCell.file = GlobalParentArray.sharedInstance.globalParentArray[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item].image
            //GlobalParentArray.sharedInstance.globalParentArray[indexPath.item][indexPath.item].image

        //this just returns 7 cells in each outer cell
        //innerCell.imageCell.file = self.partArray[indexPath.item].image
        innerCell.imageCell.loadInBackground()
        innerCell.imageCell.layer.masksToBounds = true


        return innerCell
    }


}
```

this is kind of how i imagined achieving this but don't seem able to get anything to display.

```
//innerCell.imageCell.file = GlobalParentArray.sharedInstance.globalParentArray[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item].image
```

---- EDIT -----

so one of my arrays in the multi dimensional array was empty which caused it to not populate anything.

```
innerCell.imageCell.file = GlobalParentArray.sharedInstance.globalParentArray[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item].image
```

now produces a result but only shows items for index 0??

[image]

when i print
  print(GlobalParentArray.sharedInstance.globalParentArray[collectionView.tag].count)`

i get 0 then immediately followed by the actual number of elements in the array.

```
INDEX::::::0
INDEX::::::7
```

Comment: you should check if `dequeueReusableCell` returns a cell? or you register this cell else where?

Comment: how is your imagecell created? and keep in mind that path and file to local images can change between starts

Comment: if you have an UIImageView you need create an Image to set it to the view

Comment: The image cell works fine (when using the static array (self.packArray), its actually a PFImageView and pulls a file from a parse server.  Im trying to read the data out of the GlobalParentArray as item[0] here should be the data that corresponds to the first cell of the outer collectionView, however i don't know how to get reference to the first cell of the outerCollectionView

Comment: what this line `print(GlobalParentArray.sharedInstance.globalParentArray[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item].image)` if you add it as debug?

Comment: <PFFile: 0x608000252b10>
<PFFile: 0x600000256170>
<PFFile: 0x60000005c140>
<PFFile: 0x6080002565c0>
<PFFile: 0x608000256c50>
<PFFile: 0x600000053c20>
<PFFile: 0x6080002566e0>
<PFFile: 0x608000252b10>
<PFFile: 0x600000256170>
<PFFile: 0x60000005c140>
<PFFile: 0x6080002565c0>
<PFFile: 0x608000256c50>
<PFFile: 0x600000053c20>
<PFFile: 0x6080002566e0>
fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)

Comment: which is too many items.  there are currently 10 items in the outer array, and 10 items in GlobalParentArray.sharedInstance.globalParentArray.

Comment: print(collectionview.tag) gives: 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
and then more as you scroll down

Comment: ok - restart it with a new project and empty controller - and develop step by step. add only one PFImageView to a UIView and check if it loads the image. then the next error can be: the image is white but you see only an cropped image. the next possible error: is the PFImage visible? you can see this in 3D debug view - more ideas i don't have

Comment: thanks, i might have to look at doing it differently.  i thought you would be able to get reference to other collection cell index.

Comment: you have to go step by step to see which part is broken. a hard way of debugging ;)

Comment: not too much - but it counted twice if you compare the object id `0x608000252b10`

Comment: your right they're all duplicate.  checked DB, 7 items in first table. 14 PFFile printed